# Moving 7+-letter words to file

Tags: c#

How can I move all words of seven letters or more in one string to another?

I know that I need a `foreach` loop to go through each character, and some sort of way of seeing whether the next character is blank while using a counter; then, if the next char is blank, see whether the counter is greater than or equal to seven, then move what was just there to a new string, then into a file.

Comment: Try to show some code at least when it comes to asking a question in Stack Overflow. That way you'll find it easier to understand. Anyways, welcome to this site. If you need to reply to a comment just use @ followed by the name you want to tag.

Comment: @puretppc if you want to discuss `proof of effort` check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179035/147423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)'s [`Where` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string strBigText = Console.ReadLine();
IEnumerable<string> words = strBigText.Split(" ").Where(o => o.Length >= 7);
```

This is going to split your text at every space, creating an array of strings, then retrieve only the elements (strings) that have a length greater than or equal to 7.

Comment: Yes LINQ is definitely the nicer solution.

Comment: So how would I implement this with a user input, by using the readline command? I'm confused about where the strings are coming from in this snippet of code.

Comment: See the edit. `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, so simply use that.

Comment: One last thing how do i display/save the strings that are greater than 7 letters?

Comment: @user3072763 `foreach(string s in words) { Console.WriteLine(s); }`

Comment: @BrunoLM Thank you so much! You have helped a lot, as you can probably tell im a newbie to this programming lark, but i hope to get better at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.split

```
string[] array = yourString.split(' ');
list<string> longStrings = new list<string>();

  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

     if(array[i].length >= 7){

        longStrings.add(array[i]);
     }
  }
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend RegExp for this (http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

At the top of your code, say:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then, in your routine, just go:

```
        string input = textbox1.Text; // or wherever else you get your string from
        MatchCollection matches = new Regex(@"(^|\b)\w{7}\w*(\b|$)").Matches(input);

        string[] results = new string[matches.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i != matches.Count; i++)
            results[i] = matches[i];

        //Now results will be an array of the 7-letter words.
```

Comment: Instead of `\w{7}\w*`, I think you can do `\w{7,}`.